# Android Separate TextView color and overflow color

Tags: android, overflow, textcolor

I want to set all the text in my activity to a certain color and I have acheived that with

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
```

The issue is that also changes the color of the text in my overflow options and they become hard to read. Is there a way to leave the overflow text colored black and have custom colors for the textviews?

Answer (score 1):

Every textview textColor can be set programmatically or in the xml that describes the view.

android:textColor="#FFFFFF";   //hex code for white

textView.setTextColor(Colors.White) // int value, can be hex value, or constants

Comment: I am aware of that but I avoid setting the color in the xml so I can have different themes and colors. I could individually set each textview at runtime but that is so inefficient. There should be a line I can add to my style to do this.